# Login page wordpress tagline remove

Tags: wp-login-form

I changed the Title and Tagline of my Wordpress site. But the tagline on the login page shows "Wordpress". How do I change that. Anyone can help to solve this?

Regards,
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

this code on the functions.php change your logo on wp-login.php, also you can style it throw here

```php
function custom_wplogin() { ?>
  <style type="text/css">
    body.login div#login h1 a{
      background-image: url(<?= home_url()?>/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/yourlogo.png);
      width: 220px;
      height: 166px;
      background-size: 220px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    body{background-color:#e4c854 !important;}
  </style><?php
}
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts','custom_wplogin');
```